# Vagrant + VirtualBox stuck at "EXT4-fs: re-mounded. Opts: (null)

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to learn how to use Vagrant with Laravel Homestead. When I run `vagrant up`, the line `Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...` is repeated about 30 times over a course of 5 minutes before the line `Machine booted and ready!` appears.

I turned on GUI mode to see what's happening. The last line to appear before hanging is

```
EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
```

After about 5-10 minutes, the screen instantly changes to the login screen. Why is it hanging?

I'm using the latest versions of Vagrant and VirtualBox on Windows 8.

**Edit: Vagrantfile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
  end

end
```

Comment: Paste the `Vagrantfile` here

Comment: I pasted the Vagrantfile.

Comment: Ok, I saw it. The first time to run `vagrant up`, it takes time, because it need download the image box. After up, if you run `vagrant reload` or `vagrant provision`, it should be faster.

Comment: It's still taking the same amount of time. Even if I start the virtual machine directly through VirtualBox, it still takes a long time.

Comment: it likes an issue in ubuntu only. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219277&page=2, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254573, http://askubuntu.com/questions/465193/14-04-pxe-slow-boot-process-udev-upstart-systemd,